# Can't convert string to system.Net.HttpContent

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient

Here I'm trying to get data from the services:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ValidateSesion()
{
    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>{
        { "productId", "1" },
        { "productKey", "Abc6666" },
        { "userName", "OPPO" },
    };
    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values, Formatting.Indented);
    // var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(json);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    var response = await client.PostAsync("http://172.116.12.172:8014/iadmin/validate", json);
    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return Ok(responseString);
}
```

If I make any PostMan call, like below, the data i get looks like this:

```
{
    "productId": "1",
    "productKey": "Abc6666" 
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the full stacktrace of your error? This can help us to identify the precise place where error occurs...

Comment: None of the PostAsync methods accepts a string. Trying to pass a string raises a compilation error.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can't post a raw string, you have to wrap it in a StringContent:
`new StringContent(json);`

This should do the trick:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> ValidateSesion()
{
    var values = new Dictionary<string, string>{
      { "productId", "1" },
      { "productKey", "Abc6666" },
      { "userName", "OPPO" },
    };

    var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(values, Formatting.Indented);

    var stringContent = new StringContent(json);

    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var response = await client.PostAsync("http://172.116.12.172:8014/iadmin/validate", stringContent);

    var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    return Ok(responseString);
}
```

Comment: To use System.Text.Json it could be `var json = JsonSerializer.Serialize( values );`